# Want to add the functionality of selecting two or more files

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to collate data from different excel files into one file.

However, now I want to add the functionality of selecting and importing data from multiple files at once.

Below is my macro:

```
Sub Import_Data()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim FileCnt As Byte


Call Entry_Point
Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
lrpaste = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select your file", MultiSelect:=True, FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*), *xls*")
If IsArray(FileToOpen) Then
For FileCnt = 1 To UBound(FileToOpen)
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen(FileCnt))
lcol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, lcol).End(xlUp).Row
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range(("A2"), Cells(lrow, lcol)).Copy WB1.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & lrpaste)

Next FileCnt

End If
OpenBook.Close False

Call Exit_Point
End Sub
```

I tried but the macro is not working properly. It selects multiple files; however, it does not copy data of all the files selected. Now I'm confused on how to make the macro do the same thing but with multiple files at once.

The previous macro which takes one file at a time:

```
Sub Import_Data()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook



Call Entry_Point
FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*), *xls*")
Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
lrpaste = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select your file", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*), *xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
lcol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, lcol).End(xlUp).Row
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range(("A2"), Cells(lrow, lcol)).Copy WB1.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & lrpaste)
OpenBook.Close False

End If


Call Exit_Point
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't increment the value of `lrpaste` after copying each file

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: Welcome to SO!

In order to help others find and reuse useful questions and answers, please consider editing your question title to match the guideline at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put line update lrpaste into your for loop. Otherwise data is overrode.

```
For FileCnt = 1 To UBound(FileToOpen)
    lrpaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen(FileCnt))
    lcol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, lcol).End(xlUp).Row
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range(("A2"), Cells(lrow, lcol)).Copy 
    WB1.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & lrpaste)

Next FileCnt
```